# Gatsby Netlify build error: Can't resolve '../components/GridTemplate/GridTemplate.js' in '/opt/build/repo/src/templates'

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

This started happening suddenly when debugging a seemingly unrelated error on Netlify build. I do not have this issue locally. I've cleared my cache, deleted my package-lock and node module folder and updated everything, as well as ran a build without cache on Netlify. I've checked the file/folder names for case sensitive also. What could it be?

[image]

One of the templates the component is used:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import GridTemplate from '../components/GridTemplate/GridTemplate.js'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
...

class Mediums extends Component {    
  render() {
    let allTitles = []
    this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach( post => {
      allTitles.push(post.node.frontmatter.title)
    })
    return (
      <div style={{position: "absolute", width: "100%", height: "100%", overflow: "hidden", overflowY: "scroll"}}>
        <HeaderMeta subTitle={this.props.pageContext.medium} itemGroup={this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark}/>
                 
        <GridTemplate 
          data={this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges} 
          title={this.props.pageContext.medium}
          pastUrl={this.props.location.pathname}  
        />
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Mediums
```

The GridTemplate component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import S from './imageGrid.module.sass'
import ArtImage from '../ArtImgae/ArtImage.js'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import { arrowSvg } from '../../img/svg-index.js'
import InlineSVG from 'svg-inline-react'
import Header from '../Header/Header.js'

import 'typeface-alegreya-sans-sc'
import 'typeface-cinzel-decorative'
import 'typeface-cinzel'

class GridTemplate extends Component {
  
  render() {
    const postLinks = this.props.data.map( post => {
      const frontmatter = post.node.frontmatter
      return (
        <div key={post.node.fields.slug} className={S.imageItem}>
          <Link 
            to={post.node.fields.slug}
            //pass prop of cat / med paths for back button on art item 
            state={{pastUrl: this.props.pastUrl || null}}  
          >
            <h2>{frontmatter.title}</h2>
            <ArtImage
              fluid={frontmatter.featuredImage.childImageSharp.fluid} 
              imageData={frontmatter}
            />
          </Link>
        </div>
      )
    })
  
    
    //from context
    const title = this.props.title
    
    //const totalCount = this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark.totalCount not used
    
    return (
      <section id={S.GridTemplate}>
      
        <div className={S.headerHolder}>
          <Header to={["home", "archive"]} white={true} />
        </div>
      
        <div className={S.titleHolder}>
          <Link to = "/store" className={S.storeLink} >
            <InlineSVG src={arrowSvg} />
          </Link>  
          
          <h1 id={S.mediumTitle}>{title}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={S.imageGrid}>
          {postLinks}
        </div>
      
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default GridTemplate
```

File structure:

[image]

The component `GridTemplate.js` is used by `categorys.js` and `mediums.js`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it. Turns out my renaming of the path to the component folder to uppercase was never noticed by my Mac OS, despite appearing uppercase. On Githubs end, the path was still lower case, which was wrong. Used this [gude to rename from Githubs end.](https://github.blog/2013-03-15-moving-and-renaming-files-on-github/)

Answer (score 0):

Try again deployment to netlify after changing import type-

from

```
import GridTemplate from '../components/GridTemplate/GridTemplate.js'
```

to

```
import GridTemplate from '../components/GridTemplate/GridTemplate'
```

Comment: I had a go but for whatever reason, this broke every page and template on my site. See: https://puu.sh/GueUu/d5d29ccd45.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to deploy to Netlify:

`can't resolve '../components/search/index' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'`

My original line was:

`import Search from "../components/search/index";`

Please notice the lowercase for the directory name `search`. For some reason I had to rename the folder to uppercase `Search`, i.e.,:

`import Search from "../components/Search/index";`

and Netlify would build successfully.